# Coding conflict between two javascript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, history.js

I'm trying to get a Jekyll site setup and I want the navigation to hide when scrolling down and show when scrolling up. I also want to setup ajax loading with pushState so that I can animate page transitions. I had the navigation hiding and showing properly with scrolling until I put in the code for doing the ajax loading. Now, the navigation will hide and show properly until I click a link, then it stays shown no matter what.

I'm assuming its breaking because I'm using two different jQuery libraries, however the navigation won't work on v2 and the ajax loading won't work on v3. They both work when used on their own. I could really use some help with this.

This is what my HTML looks like for loading the files:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/history.js/1.8/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/hide-navigation.js"></script>
```

Here is the navigation.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var mainHeader = $('.cd-auto-hide-header'),
        secondaryNavigation = $('.cd-secondary-nav'),
        //this applies only if secondary nav is below intro section
        belowNavHeroContent = $('.sub-nav-hero'),
        headerHeight = mainHeader.height();
var isLateralNavAnimating = false;

    //set scrolling variables
    var scrolling = false,
        previousTop = 0,
        currentTop = 0,
        scrollDelta = 10,
        scrollOffset = 0;

    mainHeader.on('click', '.nav-trigger', function(event){
        // open primary navigation on mobile
        event.preventDefault();
        if( !isLateralNavAnimating ) {
            if($(this).parents('.csstransitions').length >= 0 ) isLateralNavAnimating = true;


                mainHeader.toggleClass('nav-open');
                $('.cd-navigation-wrapper').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
                    //animation is over
                    isLateralNavAnimating = false;
                });
                }
    });

    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if( !scrolling && !mainHeader.hasClass("nav-open"))  {
            scrolling = true;
            (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
                ? setTimeout(autoHideHeader, 250)
                : requestAnimationFrame(autoHideHeader);
        }
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        headerHeight = mainHeader.height();
    });

    function autoHideHeader() {
        var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        ( belowNavHeroContent.length > 0 )
            ? checkStickyNavigation(currentTop) // secondary navigation below intro
            : checkSimpleNavigation(currentTop);

        previousTop = currentTop;
        scrolling = false;
    }

    function checkSimpleNavigation(currentTop) {
        //there's no secondary nav or secondary nav is below primary nav
        if (previousTop - currentTop > scrollDelta) {
            //if scrolling up...
            mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');
        } else if( currentTop - previousTop > scrollDelta && currentTop > scrollOffset) {
            //if scrolling down...
            mainHeader.addClass('is-hidden');
        }
    }

    function checkStickyNavigation(currentTop) {
        //secondary nav below intro section - sticky secondary nav
        var secondaryNavOffsetTop = belowNavHeroContent.offset().top - secondaryNavigation.height() - mainHeader.height();

        if (previousTop >= currentTop ) {
            //if scrolling up...
            if( currentTop < secondaryNavOffsetTop ) {
                //secondary nav is not fixed
                mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');
                secondaryNavigation.removeClass('fixed slide-up');
                belowNavHeroContent.removeClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
            } else if( previousTop - currentTop > scrollDelta ) {
                //secondary nav is fixed
                mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');
                secondaryNavigation.removeClass('slide-up').addClass('fixed');
                belowNavHeroContent.addClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
            }

        } else {
            //if scrolling down...
            if( currentTop > secondaryNavOffsetTop + scrollOffset ) {
                //hide primary nav
                mainHeader.addClass('is-hidden');
                secondaryNavigation.addClass('fixed slide-up');
                belowNavHeroContent.addClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
            } else if( currentTop > secondaryNavOffsetTop ) {
                //once the secondary nav is fixed, do not hide primary nav if you haven't scrolled more than scrollOffset
                mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');
                secondaryNavigation.addClass('fixed').removeClass('slide-up');
                belowNavHeroContent.addClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
            }

        }
    }
});
```

and finally the ajax.js

```
( function( $, History, undefined ) {

    if ( !History.enabled ) {
        return false;
    }

    var $wrap = $( "#wrap" );

    $wrap.on( "click", ".page-link", function( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        if ( window.location === this.href ) {
            return;
        }

        var pageTitle = ( this.title ) ? this.title : this.textContent;
            pageTitle = ( this.getAttribute( "rel" ) === "home" ) ? pageTitle : pageTitle + " — Acme";

        History.pushState( null, pageTitle, this.href );

    } );

    History.Adapter.bind( window, "statechange", function() {

        var state = History.getState();

        $.get( state.url, function( res ) {
            $.each( $( res ), function( index, elem ) {

                if ( $wrap.selector !== "#" + elem.id ) {
                    return;
                }

                $wrap
                    .html( $( elem ).html() )
                    .promise()
                        .done( function( res ) {

                            if ( typeof ga === "function" && res.length !== 0 ) { // Make sure the new content is added, and the 'ga()' method is available.
                                ga('set', {
                                    page: window.location.pathname,
                                    title: state.title
                                });
                                ga('send', 'pageview');
                            }
                        });
            } );
        } );
    } );

} )( jQuery, window.History );
```

Comment: Take a look at "no conflict" mode for jQuery

Comment: "however the navigation won't work on v2 and the ajax loading won't work on v3" then fix that. Ideally for the later version.

Comment: I was able to find an article that helped me make new code for my pushState and was able to get it working with jQuery v3. Thanks for the feedback guys.